# Symfony2 on Ubuntu ContextError Default Timezome

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu

Building an Symfony2 app on an Ubuntu 13.10 machine. And getting an error leading me to the date.timezone value in my php.ini file. This value was not set in the default build so got the following

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on   the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /var/www/test9/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 5419
```

In this lamp stack the .ini file is located at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and Ive edited it with US/Pacific, America/Los Angeles & PST ... but none of those edits have removed the error. I've tried restarting httpd afterwards, but not sure where to turn from here.  A test phpinfo() points to the correct location. So not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: if you're using `php-fpm` a `httpd` restart does not cause a config-reload. Try `service php5-fpm reload` or `restart`. otherwise check for dublicate entries in your `php.ini` that might be overriding your previous rule ... and make sure you not only set `date.timezone` but uncommented the  setting (aka removed the leading `;` ). further if you're trying to invoke a symfony2 command when facing the exception...your php-cli might be using a different `php.ini` - you can find you cli's `php.ini` by executing `php -i | grep ini`.

Comment: Thx for the comment. I think I discovered this on my own. IT was the semi-colon comment syntax I wasn't familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

This was a classic dumb mistake. I had added the correct date.timezone = UTC value to both my apache2 and cli php.ini file. I just had not realized the semi-colon was a comment in that format. So it wasn't registering. It works now ... though note, make sure you've updated the timezone value in both apache2.conf and cli to avoid errors